# Executing a block of code before the operator instance gets executed in DAG

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow.I have a requirement like invoking an api to update the status of the task as RUNNING when the job starts running in airflow.We are using a custom operator and I can not make any changes in the operator since other teams also using the same operator.
for example I have 4 tasks t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4
when the task is about to start I have to call an api and update the dag status as RUNNING and when ever each task starts running I have to update the task as RUNNING.

Comment: two closely related alternatives (none are very tidy / robust) **[1]** place a task to invoke the status-update API before your actual task **[2]** or place it alongside (so that it depends on same set of tasks and is triggered parallely)

Comment: I do not want to create a separate task for status update.